# .deb packaged python wheel files differ from the unpackaged ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, debian, deb

I have to pack Python wheels into `.deb`, and for that I use simple `debian/rules`:

```
%:
    dh $@
```

And I have a `pipdebs.install` file:

```
#!/usr/bin/dh-exec

../external/python3.10/wheels /usr/lib/python3.10/.cache/pip/
../external/python3.10/requirements.txt /usr/lib/python3.10/.cache/pip/
```

But the problem is that when I build `.deb` and extract `wheels` directory from `data.tar.zst/usr/lib/python3.10/.cache/pip/wheels` then it differs from the `../external/python3.10/wheels` one.

Why is that?

Comment: Differs in what way?

Comment: @jordanm `diff -r data.tar.zst/usr/lib/python3.10/.cache/pip/wheels ./external/python3.10/wheels`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reproduced your error with `debhelper-compat (=13)`. Next time you run `dpkg-buildpackage`, pay attention to the console output. I got following (interesting) message:

```
dh_strip_nondeterminism
    Normalizing ... using File::StripNondeterminism::handlers::zip
```

Quick googling results in that

> [StripNondeterminism is a library for stripping non-deterministic
> information such as timestamps and filesystem ordering from various
> file and archive
> formats.](https://packages.debian.org/sid/dh-strip-nondeterminism)

So, that also explains why your wheels inside `.deb` differ from the ones you have outside `.deb`.

Workaround is (`YYY` is your `Package:` in `debian/control` that you don't want to perform `dh_strip_nondeterminism` on and `XXX` is the package you want to perform `dh_strip_nondeterminism` on ):

```
override_dh_strip_nondeterminism:
    dh_strip_nondeterminism --package=XXX
```

Note, that this workaround will do the `dh_strip_nondeterminism` only for  the `XXX` package and not for others `YYY`, ... packages

Comment: that works as charm without affecting other packages, definitely accepting!